# Unit testing: Is it bad practice to call public methods (for setup) while testing another method?

Tags: java, c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

This is a general question, but it may help to know that I'm working with a system that encapsulates an RPC-style (remote procedure calling) controller, which is what I'm testing. It contains public methods that change the internal state of this controller. The state of this controller can be read using public methods.

Two of the methods in this class are:

- `CreateProgramSet(...)`, which creates a "set of programs" (changes the internal state of the RPC controller) and
- `GetStatus()`, which retrieves the state of this RPC controller including program sets created with `CreateProgramSet(...)`.

To test `GetStatus()`, I'm calling `CreateProgramSet(...)` (for setup) with some hard-coded parameters and then testing the result of `GetStatus()` against a hard-coded value.

To test `CreateProgramSet(...)`, I'm doing exactly the same, except in this case `GetStatus()` is used to verify that `CreateProgramSet(...)` acted correctly.

The problem I see in this testing scenario is that now **both tests are coupled to both methods**, so if `GetStatus()` changes, both tests may fail. If `CreateProgramSet(...)` changes, both tests may fail. But most importantly, if both methods change the exact right way (without knowledge of each other's change), **both tests may pass for the wrong reason**. This is obviously an undesirable scenario. The only way I see out of this problem is testing the internals of the class, but that is frowned upon in testing.

Most examples that I found deal with methods that return a value, like an "add" method or something extremely simple which doesn't require a setup. In reality many classes get complex enough to require a setup to test the individual parts of the class. This is especially true for classes that can be in multiple states. And if a class does not store state, might as well make it a static class. Also most of the examples I found test output of data rather than change of state. Am I doing something wrong? This problem to me points to a code smell but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This question is meant to be language agnostic, but if it makes a difference, I'm working with C# and NUnit.

Comment: Too long didn't read: if 2 tests have the same precondition, you can probably configure your testing framework so that it executing the precondition before execution your tests. For JUnit, it is `@Before`.

Comment: @Tunaki That's not what the question is asking.. it's asking if it's bad practice to couple two public methods to the same test even when one of those methods is not under test, but just used for setup for testing the other method.

Comment: That's why I'm saying: "setting up" is a precondition. So it should be separated in a dedicated method that is precisely for setting up. And let the testing framework invoke that setup method before each test.

Comment: Regardless, the test will still fail for the wrong reason if the setup fails.

Comment: Nope: the setup method is not part of the test itself. If the setup fails, the test isn't even run.

Comment: @Tunaki I see your point. From what I've seen, NUnit treats an exception the same as a failure.

Comment: @LaneL, unit testing is not about testing methods, it is about testing units. As a result you should understand which scenario doesn't work in a unit, not which method doesn't work - because they all may be flawed. Java is built on OOP principles, not procedural.

Comment: @Tunaki What about the scenario where both methods are modified enough to keep the result consistent, but for the wrong reason (as described in the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is not about testing methods, it's about testing scenarios.

You take a unit, setup it, and then check that it behaves as expected. Don't think about methods too much: it is not procedural programming, it is OOP - you should test that your unit passes the most possible use-case scenarios, some corner-cases and nothing more.

P.S. if what you described is a bad practice, then no stateful class can be tested: you always setup it with some method calls, and validate with some other method calls, which means that lucky (or unlucky) composition of flawed methods may sometimes result in a correct outcome (but how often does that happen?).

Comment: >P.S. if what you described is a bad practice, then no stateful class can be tested -- that was exactly my point. Unit testing says to test scenarios in isolation, but when you need to use the public interface to check other parts of the public interface, we move away from that isolation, don't we?

Comment: Isolation from other scenarios, not from other methods

Comment: >but how often does that happen? -- not often, but you would think that the theory of unit testing wouldn't allow such scenarios to occur if done correctly.

Comment: Unit testing can't save you from incorrect code, you should remember that - it is not [formal verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification). However you don't need formal verification in 99% of software products, because they are not mission critical. So people use less safer, but much effortless techniques, which usually are sufficient enough.

Comment: Thanks, much clearer now. Also was not aware of the concept of formal verification, glad to know there's such a thing and gladder to know that most software doesn't require it.

Comment: Also it's ironic that the article for "Formal Verification" on Wikipedia "needs additional citations for verification." Made me chuckle.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good one - didn't notice :). Also an article regarding the meaning of ["mission critical"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_critical) - may be useful to know the notion, if you are unaware of it.